# Getting Max value from tensor - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

```py
a = np.array([[0, 10], [1.1, 0]])
# a.shape -> (2, 2)
arg_max = tf.math.argmax(input = a, axis=1)
# arg_max.shape -> (2, )
```

How to get the max value from `a` using `arg_max` like `[[10], [1.1]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

For your array it could be like this to get values by index:

```
[[i[j]] for i,j in zip(a,arg_max)] #[[10.0], [1.1]]
# OR
[i[j] for i,j in zip(a,arg_max)]   #[10.0, 1.1]
```

Without using `arg_max`:

```
tf.nn.top_k(a,k=1)[0].numpy()
```

Comment: thanks for writing, it helps, is there any other way to get the max value without for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Without `arg_max` you can use:

```
a = np.array([[0, 10], [1.1, 0]])
tf.reduce_max(a, axis=1).numpy()
# Output
# array([10. ,  1.1])
```